# How can i print the fastest time

Tags: java

```
class marathon {
    public static void main (String[] arguments) {
        String[] names = {"Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil", "Matt", "Alex",
                "Emma", "John", "James", "Jane", "Emily", "Daniel", "Neda",
                "Aaron", "Kate"
        };
        int[] times = {341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412, 393, 299, 343, 317, 265};
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(names[i] + ": " + times[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do formatting first.

Comment: 1) iterate/sort your array 2) find lowest value 3) print that value

Comment: You can iterate array in the same for loop you have already defined, have a variable for lowest time, and update it as times are < the current lowest time.

Comment: Just FYI, keeping a list of names and a list of times and trying to keep track of them by index is a Bad Idea.  You'd be much better off creating a class which holds a name and a time and making an array of that.

Comment: `System.out.println(Collections.min(Arrays.asList(times)));`

Comment: Use a class to store both the values and then sort though that list.

Comment: You need to explain your actual question, not just dump a block of code and expect us to infer what you want.

Comment: @MarcB your solution is not correct. According to code he needs index of fastest time so then also he can print corresponding name

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the times array and find the smallest:

```
If (times[i]<min)
    min= times[i];
```

Then print it:

```
System.out.println("fastest is:"+min);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to keep track as you iterate through all the items - ie, is the current time faster (less) than any previous time?

```
class marathon {
    public static void main (String[] arguments) {
        String[] names = {"Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton"
                          , "Suzie", "Phil", "Matt", "Alex"
                          , "Emma", "John", "James", "Jane", "Emily"
                          , "Daniel", "Neda", "Aaron", "Kate" };
        int[] times = {341, 273, 278
                       , 329, 445, 402, 388
                       , 275, 243, 334, 412, 393
                       , 299, 343, 317, 265};
        int fastestTimeIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(names[i] + ": " + times[i]);
            if (fastestTimeIndex == -1 || times[i] < times[fastestTimeIndex]) {
                fastestTimeIndex = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(names[fastestTimeIndex] + ": " + times[fastestTimeIndex]);
    }
}
```

Comment: No prob. I'd also second what @azurefrog said in the comment above - it is generally better to keep data together when they're using the same index. That means, in this example, you'd create a simple object containing name and time, and track them in just one array.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to look for smallest time and get the position on that time in the array. You can implement something like this:

```
min = ∞
min_position = 0
counter = 0
for each element in array
if element < min then
min = element
min_position = counter
end if
counter = counter + 1
end for
```

Now you have the smallest time and the position off the time in the array. Now you only have to check which value corresponds to that position in the other array

names[min_position]

Tell me if you need help!
Bye